# SQL Server: How do you insert rows where some rows might have duplicate keys?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert, sql-server-2017

I need to insert dozens of rows, but my table has a unique key and some of the inserted rows might have the same unique key as existing rows in the table.

How can I safely instruct the database to only insert the rows that don't contain duplicate keys, and ignore the duplicates?

(I was thinking along the lines of `INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS ...` but I don't think it's possible?)

Comment: You could use an INSERT INTO .... SELECT. The source for the select data doesn't need to be a table.

Comment: @Ralf Ahhh, that was the piece I was missing. That makes perfect sense. Thanks!